# Recreate sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm new to databases and I made a lot of mistakes with currently existing database in my app and I want to know how can I totally delete existing database from my app and create new one starting with database version 1? Do I need to do it programmatically or there is other methods to do it?

Comment: The "other methods" involve uninstalling & reinstalling your app or changing the database version parameter to the SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to just drop all the tables in SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade() and create tables again. That will be simple.